# Project tool swallows data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge, tools

I want to project my data into another coordinate system.

I tried using the Project tool but when I opened the attribute table after ArcGIS said it had finished it was empty.

I also tried using the merge function but it says the data has to be in the same coordinate system - which I can't do because ArcGIS loses the attributes needed to merge.

Comment: Try copying the data to a new feature class in a new file database and then Project.

Comment: If the source projection is incorrect, reprojecting it could easily collapse all the vertices to a single location. Please [edit] the question to provide your source spatial reference string and envelope extent, and the target coordinate system.